# SQL Trigger on database to restrict drop/alter/create syntax error, despite following tutorial, ON is not valid at this position?

Tags: mysql, sql, debugging, triggers, syntax-error

Working on a security DDL trigger for a database and want to restrict non-admins from creating/dropping database, I have created this trigger and put it below all the other code (create tables etc) in the database script.

```
CREATE TRIGGER alert_table

ON DATABASE

FOR CREATE_TABLE, DROP_TABLE, ALTER_TABLE

AS

BEGIN

IF IS_MEMBER ('admin') = 0

BEGIN

PRINT 'Please contact your Database Admin'

ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;

END

END

GO

CREATE
```

Note:
USER 'admin'@'localhost'

It says "ON is not valid at that position, expecting: BEFORE or AFTER", and something similar for "END". Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You followed a tutorial for Microsoft SQL Server, commonly abbreviated as mssql server, while you are using mysql.

Mssql server has [DDL triggers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/triggers/ddl-triggers?view=sql-server-ver15) which syntax follows the one in your question.

Mysql's [create trigger](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-trigger.html) syntax is different and does not have DDL triggers at all, so you cannot use triggers to handle table creation events.

Comment: Hello thanks, yes now I realise my own stupidity, I am actually using MariaDB too so does that allow what I require?

Comment: No, it does not. Mariadb is a fork of mysql, so syntax and functionality is pretty similar to mysql's. Btw, both mysql and mariadb have detailed online manuals, so if you are ever in doubt about syntax, pls check those first.